flang not found after install from AUR
I've installed flang from the AUR through
yay -Syu flang

but while it shows a successful installation
pacman -Qs flang


local/flang 18.1.8-1
ground-up implementation of a Fortran front end written in modern C++

the flang command isn't found
flang --help


zsh: command not found: flang

I've tried restarting, rebuilding, etc. but nothing seems to work.

There is no command named flang when compilers are built from code in the llvm github repositiory (aka https://github.com/llvm).  If you want to use flang as the command, you need to install (or build) flang from https://github.com/flang-compiler/flang source code.

Oh.  But then how is the new flang LLVM frontend supposed to be used?  Or is it too early in its development to be used as such and one should stick to "Classic Flang" at the moment?

Use gfortran.  classic flang is stuck at Fortran 2003 (and older standards).

Command yay -Syu flang does not install the package. It is "upgrade system" only. For install, use command yay -S flang.
yay has these parameters:

-S for install package
-Ss for search package
-F for search program name in a packages
yay -Syu for upgrade system

